# $\alpha\ge 2\Rightarrow \alpha^{\beta}\ge\alpha\beta$: is my proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, ordinals

> Prove that $\alpha\ge2\Rightarrow\alpha^{\beta}\ge\alpha\beta$.

Let's use transfinite induction.

1. $P(0)$

$\alpha^{0}\ge\alpha\cdot0\iff1\ge0$.

2. $P(\beta)\Rightarrow P(\beta+1)$

Let's multiply $\alpha^{\beta}\ge\alpha\beta$ by $\alpha$: $\alpha^{\beta+1}\ge\alpha\beta\alpha\ge\alpha(\beta+1)$

$(\beta\alpha\ge\beta+1$ with $\alpha\ge2$
[image: beta multiplied alpha >= beta plus one for alpha>=2]
).

Another way for $\beta\alpha\ge\beta+1$:
$$\beta+\beta\alpha\ge\beta+\beta+1$$
$$\beta(1+\alpha)\ge\beta(2+1)$$
$$1+\alpha\ge 3$$ is true when $\alpha\ge2$, naturally.

3. $P(\beta)\Rightarrow P(\gamma)$

($\gamma$ is a limit ordinal such that $\gamma>\beta$).

$\gamma>\beta \Rightarrow \gamma=\beta+\sigma.$ Let's multiply $\alpha^{\beta}\ge\alpha\beta$ by $\alpha^{\sigma}$: $\alpha^{\gamma}=\alpha^{\beta+\sigma}\ge\alpha\beta\alpha^{\sigma}\ge\alpha(\beta+\sigma)=\alpha\gamma$.
We need to verify $\beta\alpha^{\sigma}\ge\beta+\sigma$:

$$\beta\alpha^{\sigma}\ge\beta+\sigma$$
$$\beta+\beta\alpha^{\sigma}\ge\beta+\beta+\sigma$$
$$\beta(1+\alpha^{\sigma})\ge\beta(2+\sigma)$$
$$1+\alpha^{\sigma}\ge2+\sigma$$
$$\alpha^{\sigma}\ge1+\sigma$$
From $\beta<\gamma$, $\gamma=\beta+\sigma$, and the fact that gamma is a limit ordinals while beta is not, I think, follows that $\sigma$ is also a limit ordinal. So, also considering the smallest possible alpha (the inequation would then naturally hold for any bigger ones),
$$2^{\sigma}\ge\sigma,$$ which is true ($2^{\omega}=\omega$, for example).

I'd like to know whether my proof is correct or not, and if it is, whether it's rigourous enough. It would also be great to see alternative ways of proving this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of number is $\beta$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Just an ordinal (at least it's all the text of the exercise says). I think a countable ordinal may be implied, since the exercise goes after some theorem about countable ordinals in the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing is definitely not a proof of $\beta \alpha \geq \beta+1$. In particular, the graph you drew is of a function of natural numbers and says nothing about a function of ordinals.

Also, $\beta + \beta +1 \neq  \beta(2+1)$, so that part is also wrong.